# Variable value is not incremented in the catch block

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This is the code to fetch all the results from the website.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let students = [];

let rollPrefix = '387EA';
let regPrefix = 'EA87S18';
let currRoll = 80;
let currReg = 80;
let i = 0;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, // Show the window for debugging
        slowMo: 150 // slow down by 50ms
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

    let rolltemp = rollPrefix + pad(currRoll,3);
    let regTemp = regPrefix + pad(currReg,3);

    while(i < 4){
        await page.goto('http://orissaresults.nic.in/CHSE');

        await page.type('#txtRollNo', rolltemp);
        await page.type('#txtRegNo', regTemp);

        const element = await page.$("#divCaptch");
        const text = await (await element.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();

        await page.type('#txt_UserCaptcha', text);
        await page.click('#btnSubmit');

        page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
            await dialog.dismiss().catch(() => {
                console.log(dialog.message());
                return new Result(TestStatus.FAIL, dialog.message());
            })})

        try{
            await page.waitForNavigation()
            await page.waitForSelector('table');

            const RollNO = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[0].cells[1].innerText.trim();
            });
            const Name = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[2].cells[1].innerText.trim();
            });
            const RegNo = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[1].cells[1].innerText.trim();
            });
            const Total = await page.evaluate(() => {
           return document.querySelectorAll('table')[3].rows[8].cells[0].innerText.trim();
            });

            let student = new Student(RollNO,Name,RegNo,Total)
            students.push(student)
        }catch{
            currReg++;
            continue;
        }
        currRoll++;
        i++;
    }

  await browser.close()
  // let json = JSON.stringify(students);
  // storeData(json,'test.json')

})();

// function delay(time) {
//     return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
//         setTimeout(resolve, time)
//     });
// }

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

class Student {
  constructor(roll,name,reg,total){
    this.roll = roll;
    this.name = name;
    this.reg = reg;
    this.total = total;
  }
}

const fs = require('fs')

const storeData = (data, path) => {
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(path, data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Here the variable value of currReg stays the same pls help
The code tries each roll no and reg no combinations but there are some reg no that doesnt match with roll no so in the code the roll no should stay the same but the reg no should increase by one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what should happen with each combination, but here's an implementation which inputs all combinations. Below a short explanation:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let students = [];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, // Show the window for debugging
        slowMo: 150 // slow down by 50ms
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    const rollPrefix = '387EA';
    const regPrefix = 'EA87S18';
    let currRoll = 80;
    let currReg = 80;

    while(i < 4){
        while(j < 4) {
            let rolltemp = rollPrefix + pad(currRoll,3);
            let regTemp = regPrefix + pad(currReg,3);
            console.log("rolltemp = ", rolltemp, " regtemp = ", regTemp);

            await page.goto('http://orissaresults.nic.in/CHSE');

            await page.type('#txtRollNo', rolltemp);
            await page.type('#txtRegNo', regTemp);

            const element = await page.$("#divCaptch");
            const text = await (await element.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();

            await page.type('#txt_UserCaptcha', text);
            await page.click('#btnSubmit');

            page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
                await dialog.dismiss().catch(() => {
                    console.log(dialog.message());
                    return new Result(TestStatus.FAIL, dialog.message());
                })})

            try{
                await page.waitForNavigation()
                await page.waitForSelector('table');

                const RollNO = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[0].cells[1].innerText.trim();
                });
                const Name = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[2].cells[1].innerText.trim();
                });
                const RegNo = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].rows[1].cells[1].innerText.trim();
                });
                const Total = await page.evaluate(() => {
               return document.querySelectorAll('table')[3].rows[8].cells[0].innerText.trim();
                });

                let student = new Student(RollNO,Name,RegNo,Total)
                students.push(student)
            } catch {
                continue;
            }
            currReg++;
            j++;
        }
        currReg = 80;
        j = 0;
        currRoll++;
        i++;
    }

  await browser.close()
  // let json = JSON.stringify(students);
  // storeData(json,'test.json')

})();

// function delay(time) {
//     return new Promise(function(resolve) {
//         setTimeout(resolve, time)
//     });
// }

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

class Student {
  constructor(roll,name,reg,total){
    this.roll = roll;
    this.name = name;
    this.reg = reg;
    this.total = total;
  }
}

const fs = require('fs')

const storeData = (data, path) => {
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(path, data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

so, assuming you want **all** combinations of pairs {currentRol, currentReg}, you'll definitely need two loops. There are gonna be 4x4=16 combinations in total (I assume, basing on `i < 4` condition). First mistake which you made was assigning `regTemp` **before** while loop, effectively not changing the strings entered to the inputs, only some unused, temporary values (currentRoll, currentReg). So, first and foremost is to move `rollTemp` and `regTemp` definitions into the while loop. Now, as I said, you're gonna need two nested loops, as you need to generate all possible combinations (for each `currentRol`, all `currentReg`s). One more thing to remember is that you'll have to *reset* currentReg with each outer loop iteration, as you want to test each reg for given roll.

**Note about variables' scopes**

This is a great example why variables scopes are critical when programming. Not only it increases readability and comprehensibility of the given code - it prevents other functions/scopes from using symbols which do not really belong to them. Please notice where the variables definitions are within my snippet. Probably it's not perfect, but why would you pollute global namespace as in your example?